# C#: override method in initialization

Tags: c#, java, android, xamarin

In android java if I want to use my view from not original thread I write so:

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        String text = (String) msg.obj;
        myTextView.setText(text);
    }
};
```

And all works fine. But in xamarin C# I write:

```
Handler h = new Handler()
{
    public override void HandleMessage (Message msg)
    {

    }
};
```

and see `invalid initializer member declarator`

How to reload `HandleMessage` method? Can I use my view from another thread with any another way?

---

Edit:
@AntP, this way does not work in xamarin: `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.` But thanks for your support.

Solution:

```
mActivity.RunOnUiThread(delegate
{
    mTextView.Text = ("Test");
});
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Android.  Removed the tag.

Comment: @Simon, since the class is defined in the Android SDK, it sure seems to have more than "nothing" to do with Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot override methods inside object initializers. You will have to declare a class that inherits `Handler` and overrides `HandleMessage`:

```
public class MyHandler : Handler
{
    public override void HandleMessage (Message msg)
    {
        // Some stuff
    }
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx):

> Anonymous types contain one or more public read-only properties. No
>   other kinds of class members, **such as methods** or events, are valid.
>   The expression that is used to initialize a property cannot be null,
>   an anonymous function, or a pointer type.

Hence, anonymous types can only contain public properties. Not methods.

Comment: More to the point, C# does not have anonymous classes (of that sort).

Comment: @KirkWoll Thanks, updated my answer to note that fairly important point.

Comment: Actually, what I mean is that in Java there are "anonymous classes" and in C# there are "anonymous types".  Despite the similar sounding names they are very different concepts.  In Java, an "anonymous class" is an inline *subclass/implementation" of a particular class or interface.  In C#, it's just an adhoc type (that always extends `object`) that declares a bunch of properties.  It is because it doesn't extend a real type that it does not participate in polymorphism and is thus the principal point of confusion coming from Java.

Comment: The problem with this approach is there is then no way to access the parent class without passing in a reference to that object. Is there some way around this?